# Is there any way to run a method/function in ProcessBuilder?

Tags: java

`ProcessBuilder` is usually used to run external programs, like

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("command", "Arg1", "Arg2");
```

Now I want to run a function using `ProcessBuilder`, such as:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(Foo, param1, param2);
```

You may wonder why not just invoke `Foo` directly? like

```
Foo(param1, param2)
```

Because I want to change the system environment when running Foo. The only way I found is to use `ProcessBuilder`:

```
Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
env.put("HADOOP_HOME", "/opt/hadoop");
```

So I'm wondering if I can use `ProcessBuilder` to invoke a method/function of the current program. If you have a better idea to change the system environment when running Foo, feel free to give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Running a forked Java process is a non-trivial task. It can obviously be done, as most build systems do it, but it's not as easy as it may seem. There be many dragons, because you need to assemble a full command line, and that's quite tricky, when it comes to nasty things like a class path.

I have at one point developed a class called ForkedRun, that tries to provide a slightly friendlier API around this. I've used it in code demonstrations for a talk I gave [about unit testing compilers and other similar madness](http://www.slideshare.net/SeanFloyd/hacking-java-enhancing-java-code-at-build-or-runtime). I have always planned to turn it into a library, but alas I never had the time.

Anyway, the class is here: [**`ForkedRun`**](https://github.com/mostlymagic/hacking-java/blob/master/x_common/compiler-testing/src/main/java/org/zalando/techtalks/hackingjava/common/compiler/ForkedRun.java). Feel free to clone or steal it.

The code you'd have to write would be along the lines of

```
new ForkedRun(Foo.class)
    .withArg("first argument")
    .withArg("second argument")
    .withEnv("key", "value")
    .run();
```

but you would have to implement the `.withEnv()` method yourself.

---

But if all of that is too complicated for you, I'd wrap your current application in a shell script that sets the environment variable and just start the call in the same VM.